# Finding the K-means of the normal distribution

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis

Let $K\in\mathbb N^+$ be a parameter.

Given a distribution $q$ over the real numbers, [K-means clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) aims to find $K$ *centroids* $c_1,\ldots,c_k\in\mathbb R$ that minimize
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty q(x)\cdot \min\{(x-c_i)^2\mid i\in\{1,\ldots,k\}\}dx.
$$

We can, without loss of generality, assume that $c_1\le c_2\le\ldots\le c_k$.

> **What are the resulting centroids for the standard normal distribution $q=N(0,1)$?**

---

The solution for $K=2$ is given by $c_1=-\sqrt{2/\pi}$ and $c_2=\sqrt{2/\pi}$. The reason is that the distribution is symmetric around $0$ and the expected value given that the variable is positive equals the mean of a half-normal random variable.
I am interested in computing the result for a larger $K$, e.g.,

- What are the centroids for $K=4$?

Using [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize%201%2F2%20%28e%5E%28-1%2F8%20%28x%20%2B%20y%29%5E2%29%20%28x%20-%203%20y%29%20%2B%20sqrt%282%20%CF%80%29%20%281%20%2B%20y%5E2%29%20erfc%28%28x%20%2B%20y%29%2F%282%20sqrt%282%29%29%29%29%20%2B%201%2F2%20%28-4%20x%20%2B%20e%5E%28-1%2F8%20%28x%20%2B%20y%29%5E2%29%20%283%20x%20-%20y%29%20%2B%20sqrt%282%20%CF%80%29%20%281%20%2B%20x%5E2%29%20erf%28%28x%20%2B%20y%29%2F%282%20sqrt%282%29%29%29%29), after some simplifications, it seems that the solution is approximately $c_1\approx -1.51, c_2\approx-0.453,c_3\approx 0.453, c_4\approx1.51$.

Comment: Can the downvoter please give feedback on what is wrong with the question?

Comment: I did not downvote, but if this is simply a matter of a numerical optimization, like you indicated you did yourself using WolframAlpha, then it's not clear what you would expect from this site.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker - I am interested in finding the quantity. I was able to approximate it, just for $K=4$, but this approach is not suitable for general $k$ and doesn't give a closed-form quantity for even for $K=4$.